# TTViewController and autoresizesForKeyboard

Tags: iphone, three20

I have a TTViewController with a ScrollView. Scrollview contains some header and a view, in which I create TTTableView with cells created from TableViewCells in NIB file.

[NIB Structure http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10258635/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-18%20at%205.57.17%20PM.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10258635/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-18%20at%205.57.17%20PM.png)

Everything works fine until I touch one of UITextViews in table cells - the view is not resized and keyboard is covering most of table view. This is how the screen looks:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10258635/Screen%20Shot%202011-10-18%20at%206.02.24%20PM.png

So in effect, when keyboard is present, scrollview does not change its behavior at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself.

I've used TTTableViewController from Three20 library and used NIB file only for loading parts of views (header and cells). This way autoresize works as expected.